Relation between wedge products of Kähler forms and Ricci forms and the volume form
Given a Kähler manifold $(M,g)$ with Kähler form $\omega$ with $\textrm{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}M = n$, the volume form is given as $\frac{\omega^n}{n!}$.
As any (n,n)-form on $M$ will be a multiple of the volume form, I would like to know how the wedge products of the Kähler forms and Ricci forms that add up to bidegree (n,n) relates to $\frac{\omega^n}{n!}$.
For example, one can show that $\frac{\omega^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \wedge \rho$, where $\rho$ is the Ricci form, is equal to $R \, \frac{\omega^n}{n!}$, where $R$ is the scalar curvature. From by writing out components, I anticipate that $\frac{\omega^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} \wedge \rho \wedge \rho$ relates to the volume form by some combination of $R^2$ and the Ricci tensor squared.
Given that Kähler and Ricci forms are both (1,1)-forms I was thinking there may be a general formula relating $\frac{\omega^{n-p}}{(n-p)!} \wedge \rho^p$ to the volume form, but I can't seem to find any. Does anyone know of any references? I tried to derive one myself by writing out components but I felt like there must be a smarter way... Thanks!

There's nothing special about the Ricci form here. We can ask the same question about any $(1,1)$-form, or any $(p,q)$-form really. Then one possible attempt at an answer is to relate the wedge product to the inner product on $(p,q)$-forms. A few years ago I wrote up what happens here; see Corollaries 1.7 and 1.9. The short version is that it's difficult to see what happens for, say, $\rho^3 \wedge \omega^{n-3}$ because it will involve terms like $\Lambda(\rho^2)$ (where $\Lambda$ is the Lefschetz operator) that don't really simplify or signify anything obvious geometrically.

Thanks so much!
